# Deploy local site views to remote server site views folder

Tags: publishing, web-deploy

I'm trying to deploy the local site views files to the remote server files

So I installed Microsoft web deploy in my local system

Removed .example extension of WebDeploy.config file

and Configured the required parameters

```
 <events>
          <event name="publish:begin">
            <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.WebDeploy.PublishHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.WebDeploy" method="OnPublish">
              <tasks hint="list:AddTask">
                <default type="Sitecore.Publishing.WebDeploy.Task">
                  <!-- Publish operation int othe target database will trigger this deployment task. -->
                  <targetDatabase>master</targetDatabase>

                  <!-- Target server is optional. If omitted, operation is performed on the local server. -->
                  <targetServer>171.16.1.134</targetServer>

                  <!-- 
                    userName and password are optional. If omitted, local user identity or
                    credentials saved in Windows Vault will be used to connect to the server.
                  -->
                  <userName>admin</userName>
                  <password>xyz</password>

                  <!-- localRoot is optional. If omitted, the website root is used. -->
                  <localRoot>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93sc.dev.local</localRoot>

                  <remoteRoot>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93sc.dev.local</remoteRoot>

                  <!-- Paths, relative to the localRoot, which will be deployed to the remote location. -->
                  <items hint="list:AddPath">
                    <scripts>Scripts</scripts>
                    <views>Views</views>
                  </items>

                </default>
              </tasks>
            </handler>
```

but I'm facing the below error when I choose to publish the site from my Sitecore instance.

[image]

Is there any step I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the file Sitecore.Publishing.WebDeploy.dll in your bin\ folder. You will have to find out where you can get that file (or NuGet package), and copy it into your bin\ folder.